# How to get an image from a given dicom file using clearcanvas libraries in c#

Tags: c#, dicom, clearcanvas

Can you please help me in extracting image(binary data) from a dicom file.

Comment: Please post the code you have written so far. People generally do not like to just write your code for you.

Answer (score 2):

The question is not completely clear.  If you want a bitmap for display purposes, then this is basically a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1649358/load-dicom-image-and-display-it-using-clearcanvas-library) question.  Please see the accepted answer.

If you are just trying to extract the pixel data into a byte array, then you can use code like this:

```
DicomFile theFile = new DicomFile("c:\tmp.dcm");
theFile.Load();
byte[] thePixels = theFile.DataSet[DicomTags.PixelData].Values;
```

Comment: Is there any update to render the dicom file in to picture box using winform+ C#

Comment: @Pritish did find any way to render dicom to picture box ?