# How to get image from dicom file using clearcanvas in c#?

Tags: c#, bitmap, dicom, clearcanvas

I'm developing a small project concerned with dicom imaging. In my project, a user can choose the dicom file to view, that's all. I get byte[] from dicom, but i don't know how to get image and how i show. i'm using with clearcanvas in c#. so, if u have sample or reference, please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There has been several questions similar to this related to rendering images with ClearCanvas.  Please see the answer for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1649358/load-dicom-image-and-display-it-using-clearcanvas-library) question and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770615/how-to-get-an-image-from-a-given-dicom-file-using-clearcanvas-libraries-in-c) question.

Comment: i already read it,but,the problem is i m developing in normal win form,so,is it possible to use bitmapsource and image in win form?Another way i try is to convert byte[] to bitmap or image,
but,it occurs error,"ArgumentException was unhandled parameter is not valid".i also find the way in clearcanvas forum,but,i can't,to tell you the truth i m not too strong in technology,i really face difficult in developing,Please guide me,Steve.
Regards,
Chong

Comment: Hi Steve, I have the same question. What you think about it.